# Wordpress Themes Categories for the Admin pannel

Tags: multisite

I am working on this project and I'll have 200+ and even more by the end of the project.

I need to have all these themes show up in Admin > Appearance ?

All themes will be installed on the same wordpress site
Is there any way to arrange the themes in Categories (ex. Financial, Arts etc).

Comment: You can use "Feature Filter" option from manage themes page from back end. It helps to filter themes based on tags.

Comment: Yes you can, but you need to hardcode it from wordpress script. The themes displayed on backend by `wp-admin>themes.php`.